# axWindowsMediaPlayer Visual C++ End of File

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a problem handling the end of file state of the axWindows Media Player and then open another frame in Visual C++

Here is my function :

```html
private: System::Void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(System::Object^  sender, AxWMPLib::_WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent^  e) {

                 if (e->newState == 8) {
                     this->Hide();
                     MainForm^ frame = gcnew MainForm();
                     frame->ShowDialog();

                 }
    }
```

If I build the project, the media player render the movie, plays it and when it reaches the end of file it's called the Hide function but the frame didn't show up. I receive no error.

What should I do or what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I made a trick and display a message "Press any key to continue" and use the method keydown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation you should try to catch an exception, and read its message - it's very helpful, and helps spare some time in the future.

```
try 
{
    ...
}
catch (System::Exception^ e)
{
    System::Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
}
```